# Send email ( python smtp ) to a specific domain (not .Gmail)

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, smtplib

```
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTP

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText   

msg = MIMEMultipart()  
msg['From'] = 'example1@gmail.com'
#Sender
msg['To'] = 'example2@uc.cl'
#Receiver

msg['Subject'] = 'python'
message = ' Wena mimo, como estai mimo'
msg.attach(MIMEText(message))

mailserver = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
# identify ourselves to smtp gmail client
mailserver.ehlo()
# secure our email with tls encryption
mailserver.starttls()
# re-identify ourselves as an encrypted connection
mailserver.ehlo()
mailserver.login('example1@gmail.com', 'password')
#login to the account

mailserver.sendmail('example1@gmail.com','example2@uc.cl',msg.as_string())

mailserver.quit()
```

#I make a code that sends emails to differents mail(example @gmail and 
   @corporative )  but i try to send mail to  XXXXXXXX@uc.cl (https://www.uc.cl) but this mail dont receive the message

This is a code for Python3 in Ubuntu 18.04 I dont know if the problem is the port:587 or the domain uc.cl or the code, maybe the domain uc.cl takes a high level on this security
THis domain its from a University

Answer (score 0):

I assume the school mail server might try to block the mail coming from your python server.

A few things you could try...

- Sending the email while connected to the school wifi. Maybe they don't block internal traffic
- Try sending to a email server you set up just to check your code is working right
- Make a new email account yahoo, etc and login with the code above and try sending to the other accounts you can test with. This should give you a good idea what is occuring.